# Are these Quranic verses on this amulet or something satanic?

Tags: arabic-translation, sihr, translation, ruqya

My mother went somewhere for ruqya and they gave this for adding to the water we drink. I am not good at reading Arabic hand-written like this. So I want to confirm if this is something from the Quran or God forbid something haram (in which case we should throw it away), as we don't really know the person who gave it to us.

It has been sitting in my purse for a while.

I know it starts with BismiAllah-i-Rahman-i-Raheem. I understand this much. Is that a Quranic verse after? I want to make sure that it is all Quran.

---

JazakAllah khair for the comments.

It has been indicated in some comments that it is not a part of islam that we write things on paper and add to drinking water. **But I do believe and have always felt that the word of Allah brings so much barakah in one's life. Also, I keep worrying that if I am not protected by Allah for less than a nanoseond (or smallest), shaitaan will harm me as he is such a shitshow beyond words. I feel a lot of anxiety in this regard.**

However, since it is not Quran, how and where should I discard it?

[image]

Comment: It's definitly not Quran. Hard also to say that's even Arabic, but it looks like it. I can recognize some Words but the general context is lost, note that even if this was quran there is no such a thing in Islam such as adding things to the water we drink, this is completely Dajl (quackery).

Comment: @lr0 Well drinking like this is something which some scholars allowed, see https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111809/ and https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/7852/.

Comment: As for the question the writing is rather illegible, although I recognize a verse from Al-Qasida Burda, so at least some of it is not Quran.

Comment: @UmH: I didn't mention it being forbidden or Haram, but that it has nothing to do with the Islamic teachings.